# Native Java Android to Xamarin C#

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android

How would I convert this Java code to C#? I am having trouble, specifically on the constructor.

```
public class MyMediaController extends MediaController
{
    private FrameLayout anchorView;


    public MyMediaController(Context context, FrameLayout anchorView)
    {
        super(context);
        this.anchorView = anchorView;       
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) anchorView.getLayoutParams();
        lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, yNew);

        anchorView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        anchorView.requestLayout();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class in Xamarin:

```
public class MyMediaController : MediaController
{

    private FrameLayout anchorView;


    public MyMediaController(Context context, FrameLayout anchorView) : base(context)
    {
        this.anchorView = anchorView;
    }


    protected override void OnSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)anchorView.LayoutParameters;
        lp.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, yNew);

        anchorView.LayoutParameters = lp;
        anchorView.RequestLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: this.OnSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld); should be base.OnSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

Comment: Thank you, I have changed it!

Comment: Thanks, what about this? ((ViewGroup) mediaController.getParent()).removeView(mediaController);
//Add the mediaController to a FrameLayout within your DialogFragment.
((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.controlsWrapper)).addView(mediaController);

Comment: @guybrushThreepwood ((ViewGroup) mediaController.Parent).RemoveView(mediaController); 
            
            //Add the mediaController to a FrameLayout within your DialogFragment. ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.controlsWrapper)).addView(mediaController)‌​;
            // ((FrameLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Layout.Main)).AddView(mediaController)‌​; // <... change .Layout.Main to your specific view..